# Modem interface with the batch file?

Tags: cmd.exe

Is it possible to enter the modem interface with the batch file?
My try ;
`"D:\CHROME\GoogleChromePortable.exe" 192.168.1.1 /UserName=admin Password=123456`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The
[URL syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)
is like this:

```
"D:\CHROME\GoogleChromePortable.exe" "http://admin:123456@192.168.1.1/"
```

Comment: Sory but not working.

Comment: Works for me. Check the syntax well. If it still doesn't work : [Edit[(https://superuser.com/posts/1578944/edit) your post with the command you are using and the error.